# Как остановить анимацию при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте после загрузки страницы она через 2 секунды автоматически прокручивается:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var fsHeight = $("#first_screen").height();    

    setTimeout (function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:fsHeight}, 800);
    }, 2000);

});
```

Как отменить автоматическую прокрутку по таймеру, если пользователь уже начал крутить страницу сам?

**UPD:**

*Сделал так. Насколько верное такое решение?*

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var fsHeight = $("#first_screen").height();    

    var timerId = setTimeout (function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:fsHeight}, 800);
    }, 2000);

    $(window).on("scroll",function (){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: У вас всё хорошо.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение сами, не стесняйтесь оформить его как ответ на собственный вопрос, чтобы он не числился неотвеченным, а также, чтобы помочь другим участникам. На SO это не только не запрещено, но и крайне желательно.

Comment: Ваше решение вполне верно, но стоит также остановить запущенную анимацию, например так: $("html, body").stop()

Comment: Если остановить анимацию, то и автоматическая прокрутка остановится, даже если пользователь не начал крутить сам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var fsHeight = $("#first_screen").height();    

    var timerId = setTimeout (function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:fsHeight}, 800);
    }, 2000);

    $(window).on("scroll",function (){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }
    });

});
```